# "The item you requested is not available for purchase"

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I have done each and every thing said in different articles about this error. I have added the test account. I am upgrading the version code when i change project code.
In log file i am getting this purchase error
`D/Finsky﹕ [1] PurchaseFragment.handleError: Error: PurchaseError{type=3 subtype=4}`
where i am mistaking? I have also delete and clear data of my application and set version code to 1 that is default. Here is my unity code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Soomla.Store;

public class ExampleAssets : IStoreAssets{

    public int GetVersion() {
        return 1;
    }

    public VirtualCurrency[] GetCurrencies() {
        return new VirtualCurrency[]{};
    }

    public VirtualGood[] GetGoods() {
  return new VirtualGood[] {NO_ADS_LTVG};
    }

    public VirtualCurrencyPack[] GetCurrencyPacks() {
        return new VirtualCurrencyPack[] {};
    }

    public VirtualCategory[] GetCategories() {
        return new VirtualCategory[]{};
    }


    /** Static Final members **/


  public const string NO_ADS_LIFETIME_PRODUCT_ID = "1";

/** LifeTimeVGs **/
// Note: create non-consumable items using LifeTimeVG with PuchaseType of      PurchaseWithMarket
   public static VirtualGood NO_ADS_LTVG = new LifetimeVG(
    "No Adss",                                                      // name
    "No More Ads!",                                                 //   description
    "1",                                                        // item id
    new PurchaseWithMarket(NO_ADS_LIFETIME_PRODUCT_ID, 1)); // the way this  virtual good is purchased
}
```

and the other file is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Soomla;
using Soomla.Store;

public class IAPCode : MonoBehaviour {
public static VirtualItem virtualGoods = null;
// Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
StoreEvents.OnSoomlaStoreInitialized += onSoomlaStoreInitialized;
SoomlaStore.Initialize(new ExampleAssets());
foreach (VirtualGood vg in StoreInfo.Goods) {
Debug.LogError(vg.Name+"");
}

}

public void onSoomlaStoreInitialized()
{
virtualGoods = StoreInfo.GetItemByItemId ("1");
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
public void no_ads() // This function is calling from a canvas button then           error appears
{

    StoreInventory.BuyItem (virtualGoods.ItemId);

    }catch(UnityException e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }
}
}
```

The product name, id and description is same as in google play developer console and item is active. I am doing this only for no_ads item.

Comment: Try asking this on the SOOMLA forum.  Very active community and support team there: http://answers.soom.la/